# search column in whole database-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I created one db name as **valuabledata** in sql server 2008.And I create **5 tables** with in that.
I need to search one column in whole 5 table and find.which means ,one of the table have field name as **workinggraph** and another table have field name as **workingschedule** .Now I want this two fields using **%working%**. How to write query for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use your column name instead of actorID.

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%ActorID%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```